# Terminate option list after a certain option

Tags: python, argparse

CPython itself has certain command-line options that cause all further arguments to be interpreted as non-options ("terminates option list"). For example, `-c cmd` is such an option, so `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' -E` prints `[-c, -E]`; `-E` isn't recognized as an option.

Is there a way to define an option of this kind for an `argparse` parser?

Comment: The double dash '--' can be used this way.  `nargs=argparser.REMAINDER` also.  Look up them up in the argparse docs.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm familiar with both, but I don't see how to use either to solve this exact problem.

Comment: In `argparse` an Action can only process the 'nargs' strings that it's given.  The only alternative is to raise an error, or system exit (as done by a help-action).   In `optparse` the options do get the rest of `sys.argv` and can do what they want with it.  Not so in `argparse`.